# RTL and VCL memory leak

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastmm

I'm using FastMM4 in *FullDebugMode* to find memory leaks, and I'm getting a lot of complaints about `UnicodeString`, `TList`, `TParameters`, etc. instances like this:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 276
This block was allocated by thread 0x2928, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
404CFE [System][@GetMem$qqri]
408C0F [System][@NewUnicodeString$qqri]
408E40 [System][@UStrFromPWCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpbi]
408F17 [System][InternalUStrFromPCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpcii]
5C006B [Vcl.Themes][Themes.TUxThemeStyle.GetElementDetails$qqr27Vcl.Themes.TThemedScrollBar]
774861EF [GetWindowLongW]
74B6588B [Unknown function at DrawThemeParentBackground]
74B6586C [Unknown function at DrawThemeParentBackground]
74B6780B [Unknown function at OpenThemeData]
7748C5FE [Unknown function at gapfnScSendMessage]
77481B31 [Unknown function at PeekMessageA]

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20    
This block was allocated by thread 0x2928, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
404CFE [System][@GetMem$qqri]
406EB3 [System][TObject.NewInstance$qqrv]
407556 [System][@ClassCreate$qqrpvzc]
406EE8 [System][TObject.$bctr$qqrv]
814DD8 [Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.ClearActiveAggs$qqrv]
815359 [Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.ResetAllAggs$qqro]
80D8AC [Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.InternalOpen$qqrv]
6948D7 [Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.DoInternalOpen$qqrv]
69498F [Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.OpenCursor$qqro]
80CA87 [Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.OpenCursor$qqro]
69484B [Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.SetActive$qqro]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TBits
```

My current memory leak report is about two megabytes, and most of its content is like that. What is happening? Should I be concerned about `RTL` and `VCL` internals and possible memory leaks within them? And, if yes, what can I do about them?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll try to create a minimalistic application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I be concerned about RTL and VCL internals and possible memory leaks within them?

Probably not. Recent versions of the RTL/VCL are clean. I've not encountered leaks with them, although that's not to say that you won't.

In any case, the reports you present looks just like a routine memory leak in your code. When your code leaks, typically what happens is that you create an object and then fail to destroy it. The leaked object can own lots of other objects. And they are all tracked by FastMM and reported as distinct leaks. So, if you create an object that contains a string, then leaking the owning object leaks the string too.

Comment: Unfortunately FastMM isn't able to traverse the tree of objects that are not freed and simplify it for you, but if you have XE2 or XE3 then try out AQTime and it will help you identify your real objects that have leaked.

Comment: @WarrenP Last time I made the mistake of allowing AQTime onto my machine, the IDE crashed every 5 minutes!

Comment: There is some wonky thing that happened to AQTime when the last XE3 update came out. It broke AQTime so horribly that AQTime has become useless.  I wonder if it was a sneaky plot in order to subtly take back what was being given out for free. I hereby remove my seal of approval from AQTime and smartbear.  It's crappy crap.